# Calculate Herfindahl-Hirschman Index when you know the total but only observe the largest few

Tags: missing-data, gini, diversity

The Herfindahl–Hirschman Index (HHI) is a concentration measure defined as
$$H = \sum_i p_i^2,$$
where $p_i$ is the market share of firm $i$. However this assumes knowing all $p_i$ for an industry.

For my case, I know the market value $v_i$ of the largest $10$ firms in the industry ($v_1\gt v_2\gt\ldots\gt v_{10}$) and I know the industry total value $V$. So I can calculate $p_i=v_i/V$ for $i = 1, \ldots, 10.$ However, $\sum_{i=1}^{10} p_i$ is only about 40%, plus I don't know the number of firms in that industry (but I do know the largest value of any unobserved firm is less than $v_{10}$).

Is there a good way of estimating the industry HHI based on the value of the top $N$ firms plus the total industry value?

Comment: Short answer is no.  You can get a minimum for this measure (invented long before either of these economists, by the way), but that is not enough to pin it down. The fraction in the largest 10 is itself a descriptive measure that may be useful.

Comment: Since you know the largest value of any unobserved firm is less than $v_{10}$, this means that there are at least $\frac{0.6}{p_{10}}$ more firms in the industry.

Comment: @Nick Good observations.  But in conjunction with the smallest observed value of $v_i$ and a reasonable upper bound on the industry size, one can always obtain finite bounds on the possible values and in some cases those bounds are narrow enough to be useful.  Because of this, I would suggest that the fraction in the largest $10$ ought to be accompanied with a statement of the minimum value, the contribution to $H$ of the observations, and the assumed upper bound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bound the possibilities.

Let's summarize your information in a general way.  Upon dividing all your values $v_i$ by $V$ to produce $x_i=v_i/V,$ you have observed the $k=10$ largest values $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ in a list $\mathbf p$ of non-negative values of unknown length $n$ and you know or assume the sum of $\mathbf p$ is unity.  ("$k$" is the "$N$" of the question--I need "$N$" for another purpose later on.)

By definition,

$$H(\mathbf p) = \sum_{p\in\mathbf p}p^2$$

is the sum of squares of all the normalized values.  *A priori,* $0 \lt H(\mathbf p) \le 1.$  (Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or the power mean inequality for the upper bound.)

**Let's find the best possible upper and lower bounds on $H(\mathbf p)$ *based on the partial data.***

To this end, let $m = \min(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$ be the smallest of your normalized observations, so that all unobserved entries in $\mathbf p$ cannot exceed $m.$ Further, let $s = x_1 + x_2 + \cdots +x_k$ be the sum of these observations.  Thus we know

1. The sum of all $n-k$ unobserved values of $\mathbf p$ equals $1 - s.$
2. All those unobserved values lie between $0$ and $m.$

Now it's mathematically possible for the unobserved values all to be equal to one another.  $(1)$ tells us that common value must be $(1-s)/(n-k),$ in which case these unobserved values contribute

$$(n-k) \left(\frac{1-s}{n-k}\right)^2 = \frac{(1-s)^2}{n-k}$$

to the value of $H.$  Because, as $n$ grows large this fraction grows arbitrarily small, **the best lower bound for $H$ must be just the part we can compute from the observations, equal to $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2.$**  Generally, when  you have an upper bound $N \ge n,$

> $$X^2 + \frac{(1-s)^2}{N-k} \le H(\mathbf p).$$

---

**To find an upper bound,** fix an arbitrary $n\ge k$ for consideration and maximize the sum of the $n-k$ remaining unobserved values subject to the constraints that (1) they are non-negative and (2) sum to $1-s.$

This is straightforward to do using Calculus, but it's even simpler to note that if two of these unobserved values are nonzero, say $p_i$ and $p_j,$ then because $$(p_i+p_j)^2 + (0)^2 = p_i^2 + p_j^2 + 2p_ip_j \gt p_i^2 + p_j^2,$$ you can increase $H$ by combining these two values into their sum and a zero value, *provided the sum does not exceed m.*  It then follows easily (and intuitively) that **the maximum is attained by dividing the remaining total $1-s$ into portions equal to $m$ plus one smaller amount left over.**  That is,

- $n-k$ must exceed $(1-s)/m$ and
- A maximum is attained by setting $j = \lfloor (1-s)/m\rfloor$ values to $m$ and one more value to $1 - s - jm.$

**To summarize,** write $X^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_k^2$ to account for the contribution to $H$ from the normalized observations $x_i = v_i/V, i=1,2,\ldots, k.$  If $m=0$ we're done: $H(\mathbf p) = X^2$ and all remaining unobserved values are zero.  Otherwise,

> let $j = \lfloor (1-s)/m\rfloor$ be the greatest integer less than or equal to $(1-s)/m.$  Let $N$ be an upper bound for $n.$  Then $$ X^2 + \frac{(1-s)^2}{N-k} \le H(\mathbf p) \le X^2 + j m^2 + \left(1 - s - jm\right)^2.$$ When $s\lt 1$ and no upper bound for $n$ can be proposed, the lower bound cannot be exactly attained but is approached arbitrarily closely for large $n.$  The upper bound can always be attained.

---

**Example**

In the question, $k=10$ and $s=40\% = 0.4.$  Because we aren't given $m,$ *which is a crucial statistic for bounding $H(\mathbf p),$* I have created some sample data $x_i$ consistent with this information:

```
0.053 0.050 0.047 0.044 0.041 0.039 0.036 0.033 0.030 0.027
```

Thus

$$X^2 = 0.053^2 + 0.050^2 + \cdots + 0.027^2 = 0.01667$$

and $m = \min(x_i) = 0.027.$  Compute

$$j = \bigg\lfloor \frac{1 - s}{m} \bigg\rfloor = \bigg\lfloor \frac{0.6}{0.027} \bigg\rfloor = \lfloor 22.2\ldots\rfloor = 22.$$

Therefore

- There must be at least $\lceil 22.2\ldots \rceil = 23$ additional firms in the market.
- The H-H index can be as little as $X^2$ itself, but $n$ (the total number of firms) must be large in such a case.  For instance, if the total is no more than $N=100$ firms, then the minimum is attained by giving each of the remaining $N-k = 90$ firms an equal share of $(1-s)/(N-k) = 0.6/90,$ which thereby contribute the amount $$\frac{(1-s)^2}{N-k} = \frac{0.6^2}{90} = 0.004$$ to $H,$ giving a minimum of $X^2 + 0.004 = 0.02067.$
- The H-H index can be as great as $$X^2 + jm^2 + (1-s - jm)^2 = 0.01667 + 22(0.027)^2 +  (1 - 0.4 - 22(0.027))^2 = 0.032744.$$